# Moving Query to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I'm updating some old code that has deprecated MySQL functions. But for some reasons I cannot get all the results from the column. The strange part is that if I run the query directly on the server I get all results fine. So this is an issue with PHP getting the results, not the MySQL server or my query.

Here is the new and old code:

My current updated code:

```
$sql = "SELECT user, monitor FROM users WHERE `status` = 'y'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

// This works. It shows all results
echo $row["user"];

// This does not work! Only shows one result:
$account= $row["user"];

    }
 else {
    echo 'No results';
}
```

When I use that query directly on DB server, I get all results. So the SQL query is correct. I actually also get all results as well in PHP if I echo the row directly like:

```
echo $row["user"];
```

But for some reason when I try to use it with a PHP with variable it only lists one user result.

In the past I used this but the **mysql_fetch_array** function is now deprecated

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
array_push($data, $row["user"]);
}

foreach($data as $value) {
$account = $value
}
```

I cannot use my previous code anymore as those MySQL functions are obsolete today. I need to write the results into a file and my old method worked fine. The new one using mysqli does not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you did use mysqli_ to connect with also, right? I can't see what you posted failing.

Comment: You're overwriting `$account` on each loop. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: so, did you not do `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` ? and keeping the `foreach`?

Comment: He's using MySQLi Object-oriented @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @JeanPaul98 well I know that *lol!* - why are you telling me that?

Comment: this question's unclear here. What used to work on mysql_ doesn't on mysqli_, what am I not getting here?

Comment: No you're right lol @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: What's not working is the overwriting of a variable. It's not rocket science.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Right, yet you figure that they'd adapt their mysql_ method to mysqli_ and not change it after; that's the part I don't get.

Comment: Move along folks, nothing to see here. The OP is long gone.

Comment: Yes I'm using mysqli

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add one of these `[`, and one of these `]`.

```
$account[] = $row["user"];
//      ^^ right here.
```

`$account= $row["user"];` means you're storing the value of `$row["user"]` in `$account` each time the loop executes. `$account` is a string, and it gets a new value each time.

`$account[] = $row["user"];` means you're appending each value of `$row["user"]` to an array instead.

You should not use `array_push` for this. It's overkill for appending a single value to an array. And if the array isn't defined beforehand, *it won't work at all*.

Comment: I think this is the problem. I'm overwriting the results in the variable. Reason why I always get the last result only. Could you care to explain how to do I get all results? I tried your code but I get just Array and nothing more as result. The old code I posted worked fine for me in the past but I can't get this with the new mysqli

Comment: You're seeing "Array" because you can't echo an array directly. You need to either iterate it with foreach and echo each value in it, or use something like `echo implode(',', $account)` to convert it to a string first.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be the problem. Strange, as I didn't do this before in the old code. Thanks again!